# How to trigger a touch event in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a textarea in my phonegap app form like

```
<form name="myform">
<textarea name="myTextarea" id="myTextarea"></textarea>
</form>
```

I want to set focus on this texarea after pageload and want the keyboard bring up. How can I implement this?

Thanks

Comment: From my experience it's not possible. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287478/mobile-safari-autofocus-text-field for further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('myTextarea').focus();
};
```