# Automatically Selecting Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, ios, forms, datepicker

So I have a Javascript form using a Date picker:

```
<input name="date" type="date" id="date"/>
```

I would like the input field to already be selected when the screen loads. Scenario: user on an iOS device loads this form, and the Date Picker automatically comes up, without them having to tap on the drop down element in the HTML.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `focus()` method, then you can set the focus on your input on body load, as follow:

```
<input class=".dtInput" name="date" type="date" id="date"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').onload(function(){
        $('.dtInput').focus();
    }
</script
```

Use the jquery to easily get the elements of you page

Comment: -1 jquery isn't needed and this isn't jquery. `document.getElementById(el).focus();`

Comment: This does not seem to work on iOS Safari. Is there a tweak to this code which will allow it to work on iOS devices?

Comment: may this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728166/programatically-focus-on-next-input-field-in-mobile-safari) could help you.