# catch ng-show event and focus input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I don't want to write complicated directive just to focus something. If the approach would be using the pure js it is acceptable. My question is how to catch the ng-show of angular.

```
<a ng-click="showInput=true">show</a>
<input type="text" ng-show="showInput" />
```

the above code show the input, how to focus it upon it appearance?

Comment: not sure if it's necessary for your project, but keep in mind you cannot programmatically trigger `focus` into elements on iOS devices (it has to be done via a click/tap), however you can traverse the elements once the first focus is set http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728166/programatically-focus-on-next-input-field-in-mobile-safari

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try using a simple directive like this one:

```
app.directive('FocusOnVisibility', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        //Watch the showInput model
        scope.$watch('showInput', function () {
            //If the model changes to true, focus on the element
            if (scope.showInput === true) {
                //Assumes that the element has the focus method
                //If not, then you can have your own logic to focus here
                element.focus();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

You can then use this directive in your tag as:

```
<input type="text" ng-show="showInput" focus-on-visibility>
```

Comment: doesn't work, it make sense but just doesn't work. No error found.

Comment: If it doesn't work, you shouldn't mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can add this directive:

```
app.directive('showFocus', function($timeout) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.showFocus, 
      function (newValue) { 
        $timeout(function() {
            newValue && element.focus();
        });
      },true);
  };    
});
```

and use it like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-show="showInput" show-focus="showInput">
```