# Can not focus newly created element on ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, focus

I have a part of code, where I create new elements on the fly and make them focusable.

The code is more complex, but here is a [reproducible part on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ta5b4vnv/) (when you click enter the next element is created and then focus is assigned to it):

```
$("body").on( "keypress", ".field", function(e) {
  if ( e.keyCode  == 13 ) {
      $(this).after('<p class="field" contenteditable="true"><br></p>')
      $(this).next().focus();
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

This works as expected in desktop browsers, but it failed to focus the next element on ipad (and may be on iphone)

Comment: FWIW your fiddle works fine on iPhone 4 iOS7 Safari. I don't have an iPad to test with.

Comment: Actually, I tested this on iOS simulator in Xcode and it works fine in iOS 7.1, iPad...

Comment: have you tried adding a delay between the element creation and focus?

Comment: @kid yes, I thought that setTimeout can solve the problem, but it did not work.

Answer (score -1):

> [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204571/mobile-safari-javascript-focus-method-on-inputfield-only-works-with-click) IOS/Safari only "accepts" the focus when inside a touch event handler. I triggered a touch event and inserted the `.focus()` inside it. I tried this on my iPhone3S/Safari and it works:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EbU6a/).

[Actual Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728166/programatically-focus-on-next-input-field-in-mobile-safari).

Comment: I tried the same solution for my case and I failed.