# Focus input field - iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to find my way out of the dead end that apple created by stripping down autofocus on iOS. I get it, it creates problems for some cases.

However, I'm still trying to find a proper way to focus an item **without clicking the item itself**.

I've tried auto-focusing;

```
myInput.on('blur', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        myInput.focus();
    }, 0);
});
```

I've tried focusing on document-click (anywhere in the document);

```
document.body.onclick = function () {
    s.focus();
};
```

Both solutions didn't work. Therefore, I'm needing a way to focus the field/input automatically (on page load) or by clicking anywhere on the page (instead of limiting the click to only one item).

I have a single input field that has to be filled in my case. So I don't mind having a lock on that input field (that's actually what I would prefer!).

Any ideas?

Comment: This is working for me in Chrome dev tools emulation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18729108/3632159

Comment: which one is working for you exactly?

Comment: The link leads directly to the answer I'm referring.