# How to set input focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I am developing a WebApp and want to create a kind of login screen with html. For this I have four input fields, which focus on the next field after a number has been typed in.

In osX safari this works without any problems. Unlike iOS on my iPhone. Yoo-hoo.

The problem on mobile safari is that I don’t know how to automatically "jump" to the next input field programatically (set the focus programmately). The user can do it via a button (working fine), but is there a way to do this automatically?

**See my code:**

```js
$('.text').on('input', function() {
  $(this).next('input').focus()
});
```

```css
.text {
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text" />
<input type="text" class="text" />
<input type="text" class="text" />
<input type="text" class="text" />
```

The focus is working quite fine on webBrowsers like safari or chrome but not for iPhone iOS safari like to can see in this gif - The focus get's lost and the keyboard disappears:

[image: gif]

What I've found during my research was e.g this question:

- [Programmatically focus on next input field in mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728166/programmatically-focus-on-next-input-field-in-mobile-safari)
- [Mobile Safari: Javascript focus() method on inputfield only works with click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204571/mobile-safari-javascript-focus-method-on-inputfield-only-works-with-click?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But none of the answers did the job for me because whether they are not working / they are to jerky or they use a workaround that is not really working with my styles like http://jsfiddle.net/EbU6a/194/ did.

So any help how to fix this would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am pretty sure that someone will get this problem too, I decided to answer my own question.

**So I've fixed the issue partly using this line of code:**

```
myWebView.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = false
```

I found the solution while reading the apple documentation for UIWebView.

Please see this [reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617967-keyboarddisplayrequiresuseractio).

Answer (score 0):

I am affraid iOS does not allow you to focus programatically. You can try workaround from [here](https://medium.com/@brunn/autofocus-in-ios-safari-458215514a5f)