# Mobile Safari is ignoring my autofocus jQuery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, mobile-safari

I am trying to on page load have the first form field to be automatically selected/in focus by using the focus() method in jQuery. 
This works fine on the deskop - however this doesn't appear to work on iOS in the Safari browser - can anyone suggest why not?

```
    var el = $('#txtNewUsername').get(0);
    var elemLen = el.value.length;

    el.selectionStart = elemLen;
    el.selectionEnd = elemLen;
    el.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I heard about this problem for many times.

This might be helpful [Mobile Safari: Javascript focus()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204571/mobile-safari-javascript-focus-method-on-inputfield-only-works-with-click)