# iOS Safari/Chrome Jquery/Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have a basic test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous">></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <p>Test</p>
      <form name="scan">
        Field 1
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="first" id="first">
        <br>
        Field 2
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="second">
        <br>
        Field 3
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="third">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("input:text:visible:first").focus();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works as expected in all Windows browsers.

The Jquery code does not work when loaded into Safari or Chrome on an iPhone with the latest iOS.

I also tried:

```
document.getElementById("first").focus();
```

I also put some alerts around the commands and the alerts worked but the focus did not happen into the first field.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Ken

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16601288/1719752

Answer (score 0):

You have this code

```
$("input:text:visible:first").focus();
```

You want to `focus` on the first textual `input`. You can do it like this:

```
$("input[type=text]:first").focus();
```

Where inside the square braces your selector specifies the value of the `type` attribute and we use the `:first` presudo-selector.