# iOS Safari input typing issue when clear value

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, mobile-safari

I am creating a custom clear button that clears the value of an input.

[image]

Type some text and tap the clear button, and then programmatically return focus to the input, I won't be able to continue typing. The caret is blinking, but I can't input anything when I type on the soft keyboard.

This issue occurs on iOS (13.6.1) Safari, not Chrome.

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model="value" ref="input" />
    <button @click="clear">Clear</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clear() {
      this.value = "";
      this.$refs.input.focus();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

demo: https://codepen.io/fellows3/pen/vYGyjjV

Has anyone seen this before and, if so, is there a way to prevent it?

**UPDATE:** I have noticed that this happens on a Japanese keyboard and cannot be reproduced on an English keyboard.

Comment: Maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204571/mobile-safari-javascript-focus-method-on-inputfield-only-works-with-click#answer-16601288

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't solve the problem...