# iPad browser requires extra tap after appending input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, ipad

Unsure how to describe this so bear with me:

I have a table inside an iFrame. When you double tap a cell, an input field is drawn on top of the table cell absolutely. Whatever number was in the table cell is inserted into the input box. The input box is then given the focus.

In a web browser this works fine. But in Safari on iPad -> The input draws after a double tap, inserts the number but requires either 1) the field to be tapped once more or 2) the backspace key to be hit twice before you can enter text into the field.

I'm asking primarily to see if anyone else has encountered this. If not I will put together a sample in JSFiddle etc for people to play with.

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there any hover events (eg: `onmouseover` in JS or `:hover` in CSS) on the cells?

I haven't done extensive testing, but iOS generally triggers hover events on the first tap.

Comment: No, there is a click event to highlight the cell first, but the issue still stands when that event is taken out

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7332160/730557 - 

_As of iOS 5, handlers triggered by synthesised click events are allowed to trigger focus on input elements._