# Opening keypad automatically while navigating to view in sencha touch on iOS device

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a selectfield in a view and when I am navigating to that view I want keypad opens automatically when I am moving to that view. I am trying to call focus method but it is not working,

Any one help me in this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287478/mobile-safari-autofocus-text-field

Answer (score 0):

You have to call focus on the textfield as soon as it is initialized something like below,

```
listeners: {
        initialize: function(view, eOpts) {
        Ext.getCmp('_phoneNumberId').focus();

                                         }
       }
```