# How to set cursor inside textbox after page load with jquery in ipad's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, cursor

I have an HTML5 textbox and i want to set cursor inside textbox after page loaded like when you open google in ipad?Is it possible to set the cursor in ipad and tab devices.?

I only need set cursor inside textbox code.

I tried this but not working.Please help me out with this...Thanks in advance...

```
$('#Bhairav').focus();
```

Comment: It would be better if you can post your HTML too. because there is nothing wrong with `$('#Bhairav').focus();`

Comment: <input type="text" id="Bhairav" class="customform text-red no-border blink_me"
    data-required='true'
    placeholder=" Please click here to Key Fob scanning work">

Comment: You might be getting this problem only on i-pad

Comment: this is because focusing is not possible with the iPad

Comment: this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287478/mobile-safari-autofocus-text-field/7332160#7332160

Answer (score 0):

Try to use timeout,

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#Bhairav').focus();}, 200);
```

Comment: ,I tired with that but focus is not setting on the textfield on ipad browsers.Is this code works for IPad browsers also?

Comment: Yes it'll work, should be called after rendering the page(Next to </body>).

Comment: Thanks for the response surendar but one small help can you create it in the fiddle so that i can check it in ipad browsers please.

Comment: ,Still it is not working for me,can u please create a demo fiddle so that i can check and resolve my issue.