# Text input does not get focused inside touchstart binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, knockout.js

**Issue:** I have a text input and a button (binding with knockout). Inside knockout click event I have a jquery focus which is working on any desktop but on any ios devices.

HTML:

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="SearchInput" data-bind="textInput:SearchInput" />
 <input type="button" data-bind="click:BtnClicked ">
```

Model:

```
 $('#SearchInput').on('touchstart', function (e) {
      // It shows that we get here 
      $("p").text("I am here in touchstart");
      $(this).focus();                 
 });

/////

 self.BtnClicked = function (){
   $("#SearchInput").trigger('touchstart');
 }
```

It works on any Android devices but it is not working on any ios devices (the latest Safari & Chrome). It goes inside `touchstart` binding where I see  `<p>` is getting set with new text but no luck to make it work on an ipad. I've also tried both `-webkit-user-select: none;` and `-webkit-user-select: text;` still not working.

Comment: Why are you trying to trigger `touchstart` from the button?

Comment: Will it make sense to put `$(this).focus();` inside of `self.BtnClicked` ?

Comment: @MichaelBest there is an ajax call inside the click event for that button which in success I want the text input gets focus programmatically. After some research it seems I need to bind `touchstart` first and then trigger it later in order to make it work on `ios` devices.

Comment: @gkb inside of self.BtnClicked `$(this)` does not point to the text input and beside even if we select  `$(#SearchInput)` it will defiantly work on any non-touch devices. There are some scenarios that OS on touch screen device does (ex.detecting double tap for zoom ..) and therefore it is different from desktop

Comment: Have you tried using the `hasFocus` knockout binding instead?

Comment: @MichaelBest yes I've tried `data-bind="textInput:SearchInput,hasFocus:GetFocus"` then inside `touchstart`  I'd set `GetFocus` to  true. But again it was only working on desktop and any Andriod device. It so bizarre !

Comment: What is the point of using `touchstart`? Why not just update `GetFocus` in your `click` handler?

Comment: @MichaelBest As I explained by only updating `GetFocus` it does work on any desktop but does not work on any touch device browsers. (I guess Apple doesn't want the keyboard to appear except on user demand).http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287478/mobile-safari-autofocus-text-field/7332160#7332160

Comment: @MichaelBest  this link shows you that focus is working on a desktop but not on an ipad https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/126/  try it with an ipad or iphone if you have

Comment: According to this: https://www.quora.com/Mobile-Safari-iPhone-or-iPad-with-JavaScript-how-can-I-launch-the-on-screen-keyboard/answer/Han-Wei, `.focus()` won't work in Mobile Safari within `setTimeout`. Try http://jsfiddle.net/DLV2F/2/