# How to make component appear and set keyboard focus to its input field in iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, html-input

So I figured out how to make iOS select text by using `e.target.setSelectionRange(0, 999)`:

```js
    onUp(e){
      e.preventDefault() // By default, on mouse up the caret is placed between characters. That has to be negated.
      e.target.setSelectionRange(0, 999) // Set the selection to (what is likely) all the text in the input field.
    }
```

```html
  <input @mouseup="onUp" v-model="input"/>
```

https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/ZvoEQa

However, this only works for trusted events: events that are a direct effect of user input (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted). I want to show an initially hidden Vue component when the user requests it with a click. When it has appeared, the input field inside that component should get its content selected.

I tried the following:

1. Do the setSelectionRange when the component appears (on mounted() of the component). Doesn't work, because it is not a trusted event (I think).
2. Let the click event that summons my component set the selection on the component by finding its ID. It would be an ugly solution as it does not cleanly separate my components. It also does not work, because at the time of the click, the component is not in the DOM and the ID of the input field  can't be found.
3. Adding a setTimeout to solution 2. No success: the text selection is triggered by the untrusted timeout event.

Do I want too much?

Comment: It doesn't seem that `setSelectionRange` requires an Event at all, so I don't see how it can be constrained to trusted events. `timeout` is not an Event at all, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to `setSelectionRange` if your DOM element doesn't have focus. In your codepen, it does (and you should probably be using the `focus` event there rather than `mouseup`), but when a component is mounted, it doesn't.

**Update**: This works generally, but apparently not on IOS. [This page](http://wisercoder.com/input-select-does-not-work-on-ios/) says:

> `setSelectionRange` will not work on iOS if the element doesn’t have
>   focus. Also be advised that anything revolving around giving text
>   inputs focus [is highly
>   unreliable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287478/mobile-safari-autofocus-text-field)
>   on mobile Safari.

The link there says:

> As of iOS 5, handlers triggered by synthesised click events are
>   allowed to trigger focus on input elements. Try the updated [FastClick
>   input focus
>   example](http://ftlabs.github.com/fastclick/examples/focus.html).

So we'll probably have to synthesize a `click` event on the input to get focus there.

**Update (again)**: It may be that the best you can do is select text on `focus`. I've updated my code accordingly. If `focus` works programmatically, text will be selected when the component appears; otherwise, it will be selected when you tap on the field.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showing: false
  },
  components: {
    autoSelected: {
      data() {
        return {
          text: 'hi there'
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.$refs.input.focus();
      },
      methods: {
        selectText(e) {
          e.target.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showIt() {
      this.showing = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="showIt">Show it</button>
  <auto-selected v-if="showing" inline-template>
    <input ref="input" v-model="text" @focus="selectText">
  </auto-selected>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Roy, thanks for pointing out the focus part. I added your solution to my Codepen in the part called App 2. It does not work on iOS, at least not on my phone: https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/ZvoEQa?editors=1011

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I tried all that, but iOS Safari play ball. Setting focus to the input is manageable, but having text selected seems only to be allowed when users manually put focus on the input field. I have updated the Codepen with your proposed concept, but it doesn't work: https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/ZvoEQa

Comment: It seems we're out of luck and it is just not possible to get this to behave on iOS. Therefore I accept your answer :)