# keyboard appear when ready in mobile browser with using only javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to show keyboard with selected edit text. I used `focus()` which is perfectly work for in browser. I am able to edit text when browser is ready.
Below is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allSelects = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var lastSelect = allSelects[allSelects.length - 1];
    lastSelect.focus();

    $("#main_container").click(function() {

        lastSelect.focus();

    });
});
```

but  when I load this site in mobile device then it is not appears  mobile keyboard unless touch.

please find out the solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: still i am working please use chrome or Firefox  for web page

Comment: So you mean your `<p>` tag has `contenteditable` attribute?

Comment: yes it is  contenteditable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a working snippet with your code. I changed a little the syntax to use `.on()` and `.trigger()` methods.

Maybe you can use the `.trigger()` method with `touchstart` to achieve what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allSelects = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  var lastSelect = allSelects[allSelects.length - 1];

  $("#main_container").on('click', function() {
    lastSelect.focus();
    $(lastSelect).trigger('touchstart');
  });

  $("#main_container").trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_container">
  <p contenteditable=true>Some text</p>
  <p contenteditable=true>Some text</p>
  <p contenteditable=true>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am giving you a 50 bounty for your attention and also up vote

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var allSelects = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var lastSelect = allSelects[allSelects.length - 1];
lastSelect.focus();
lastSelect.select();

$("#main_container").click(function() {

    lastSelect.focus();

});
```

});

Comment: it give a lastSelect.select is not a function error

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iOS/Safari as your mobile device, it doesn't allow setting focus unless it's in response to a user input event (i.e. touch).

> I think this is a feature of mobile Safari rather than a bug. In our
>   work on FastClick, my colleagues and I found that iOS will only allow
>   focus to be triggered on other elements, from within a function, if
>   the first function in the call stack was triggered by a
>   non-programmatic event. In your case, the call to setTimeout starts a
>   new call stack, and the security mechanism kicks in to prevent you
>   from setting focus on the input.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287478/mobile-safari-autofocus-text-field/7332160#7332160)