# Input tag's autofocus doesn't work when loading web page on iPhone or iPad

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want autofocus to work on web page load.

It works fine on PC or Android phone, but it doesn't work on iPhone or iPad.

Any solution? (I am not using react or vue.js)

Comment: Can you share some code so we can see how are you using autofocus?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus#browser_compatibility

Comment: form input focus, by jquery: `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#input1').focus(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Using Modernizr’s media query

> (function($, M) {
> // media query for minimum of 1024 pixel device width (iPad is 960 CSS pixels)
> if(M.mq('only all and (min-width: 961px)')) {
> $(function jqueryAutofocus() {
> // automatically focus the search field
> $('#header-search [name="q"]').focus();
> });
> }
> })(window.jQuery, window.Modernizr);

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287478/mobile-safari-autofocus-text-field)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment is **NOT** possible to autofocus elements. Apple wants user click explicitly the element (for instance, input). You can check here: https://caniuse.com/?search=autofocus

Also, I've found a great article speak about this question here: https://medium.com/@brunn/autofocus-in-ios-safari-458215514a5f

I hope we can delete this question in the future :)