# Auto focus text field in UIWebview

Tags: ios, input, uiwebview

I am loading a webview form in my iOS app and I want to autofocus a textfield on the form. I tried

```
NSString *focus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByName('j_captcha')[0].focus()"];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: focus];
```

But that doesnt seem to work. "j_captcha" is the name of the textfield. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me

```
NSString *evalStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setTimeout( function(){document.getElementsByName('j_captcha')[0].focus();},1000);"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:evalStr];
```

This post helped - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268931/653978